Flask + JS, Flash function doesn't work in real time after the POST action but need a refresh to be showed
Why when i use Flask + JS - Ajax the Flask return Flash doesn't work? I have to update the page to show the Flash message after the POST operation
I have this html
{% for p in cliente.pratiche %}
                            <tr>
                                <td id="idpratica_{{ p.idpratica }}" data-field="idpratica">{{ p.idpratica }}</td>
                                <td id="descrizione_{{ p.idpratica }}" data-field="descrizione" contenteditable="true">{{ p.descrizione }}</td>
                                <td id="idcliente_{{ p.idpratica }}" data-field="idcliente" style="display: none;">{{ p.idcliente }}</td>

                                <td id="idstato_pratica{{ p.idpratica }}" data-field="idstato_pratica" contenteditable="true">
                                    <select class="form-control" id="idstato_select_{{ p.idpratica }}">
                                        {% for stato in lista_stati %}
                                        <option value="{{ stato.idstato_pratica }}" {% if stato.idstato_pratica==p.stato_pratica_rel.idstato_pratica %} selected {% endif %}>{{ stato.descrizione }}</option>
                                        {% endfor %}
                                    </select>
                                </td>

                                <td id="idtipo_richiesta_{{ p.idpratica }}" data-field="idtipo_richiesta" contenteditable="true">
                                    <select class="form-control" id="idtipo_select_{{ p.idpratica }}">
                                        {% for tipo in lista_tipi %}
                                        <option value="{{ tipo.idtipo_richiesta }}" {% if tipo.idtipo_richiesta==p.tipo_richiesta_rel.idtipo_richiesta %} selected {% endif %}>{{ tipo.descrizione }}</option>
                                        {% endfor %}
                                    </select>
                                </td>


                                <td id="importo_{{ p.idpratica }}" data-field="importo" contenteditable="true">{{ p.importo }}</td>
                                <td>
                                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#confermaModifica{{ p.idpratica }}">Modifica</button>
                                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#confermaCancellazione{{ p.idpratica }}">Cancella</button>
                                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-warning" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapseExample" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseExample">
                                        Dettagli
                                    </button>
                                    
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <th colspan=6>
                                    <div class="collapse" id="collapseExample">
                                        <div class="card card-body">
                                            da compilare con tabella Eventi.
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </th>
                            </tr>

                                        <!-- Modal Modifica -->
                                        <div class="it-example-modal">
                                            <div class="modal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" id="confermaModifica{{ p.idpratica }}">
                                                <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
                                                    <div class="modal-content">
                                                        <div class="modal-header">
                                                            <h5 class="modal-title">Conferma operazione</h5>
                                                        </div>
                                                        <div class="modal-body">
                                                            <p>Vuoi procedere con la modifica ?</p>
                                                        </div>
                                                        <div class="modal-footer">
                                                            <button class="btn btn-outline-primary btn-sm" type="button" data-dismiss="modal">Ritorna</button>
                                                            <a class="btn btn-primary btn-sm text-white" onclick="confermaModifica({{ p.idpratica }})" role="button">Conferma</a>
                                                        </div>
                                                    </div>
                                                </div>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>

<script>
    function confermaModifica(idPratica) {
        const descrizione = document.getElementById('descrizione_' + idPratica).innerText;
        const idcliente = document.getElementById('idcliente_' + idPratica).innerText;

        const idstatoSelect = document.getElementById('idstato_select_' + idPratica);
        const idstatopratica = idstatoSelect.options[idstatoSelect.selectedIndex].value;

        const idtipoSelect = document.getElementById('idtipo_select_' + idPratica);
        const idtiporichiesta = idtipoSelect.options[idtipoSelect.selectedIndex].value;

        const importo = document.getElementById('importo_' + idPratica).innerText;

        var formData = new FormData();
        formData.append('descrizione', descrizione);
        formData.append('idcliente', idcliente);
        formData.append('idtipo_richiesta', idtiporichiesta);
        formData.append('idstato_pratica', idstatopratica);
        formData.append('importo', importo);
        formData.append('idpratica', idPratica);

        fetch('/pratica_edit', {
            method: 'POST',
            body: formData
        })
            .then(response => {
                if (response.ok) {
                    $('#confermaModifica'+idPratica).modal('hide');
                    //location.reload();
                } else {
                    console.error('Errore durante l\'aggiornamento del cliente:', response.statusText);
                }
            })
    }
</script>


and this the the flask backend


@pratiche_blueprint.route("/pratica_edit", methods=['POST'])
@login_required
def edit_pratica():
    descrizione = request.form['descrizione']
    idcliente = request.form['idcliente']
    idtipo_richiesta = request.form['idtipo_richiesta']
    idstato_pratica = request.form['idstato_pratica']
    importo = request.form['importo']
    idpratica = request.form['idpratica']
    pratica_obj = Pratica.query.get(idpratica)
    
    if pratica_obj:
        pratica_obj.descrizione = descrizione
        pratica_obj.idtipo_richiesta = idtipo_richiesta
        pratica_obj.idstato_pratica = idstato_pratica
        pratica_obj.importo = importo
        pratica_obj.idcliente = idcliente

        try:
            db.session.commit()
            log_this(current_user.iduser, idpratica, idstato_pratica, 'Aggiornamento')
            flash('Aggiornamento avvenuto con successo.', 'success-custom')
            return make_response('success', 200)
        except Exception as e:
            flash('Query Error #f1', 'danger-custom')
            db.session.rollback()
            return make_response("Errore edit pratica %s" % str(e), 500)
    else:
        flash('Pratica non trovata', 'danger-custom')
        return make_response('Pratica non trovata', 404)
    
    return redirect(request.referrer)

The flash message in True case of the Try isn't showed in real time but after a refresh of the page. This happens any time i use a POST request throught JS, that some times i need for more complex works and flask-form isn't enough. When i use flask-form the Flash message works properly
